# load balancer installing on database server virtual machine

Tags: linux, load-balancing, network-design

I have a simple layout of my site, a load balancer sitting in front of 3 app servers which request the database. I've 4 VMs available, 3 VMs for 3 app servers, and one VM for database. Is it wise that install the load balancer on the same VM as database? or should it be on a totally separated VM? The question arises with cost concerning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not wise to install the LB on the same VM as the database for a few reasons:

1. Network plumbing - LB's are traditionally application proxies and designed to be the public interface to an application.  This usually means some form of network segregation.  Database servers traditionally should not be accepting public traffic (using public for any client traffic).
2. Performance - LB, while not heavily impacting in smaller environments, a busy app will cause resource contention between client traffic routing and database calls.  You'll experience potential slowness due to the system trying to handle client traffic decision making and database access.
3. Security - If the app is designed to be even semi-secure, the LB will not only act as a proxy, but a basic security front end, terminating, maybe even bridging SSL traffic.  You don't want to be terminating public connectivity to the database server.
4. Troubleshooting.  Trying to troubleshoot LB issues when it's the same interface or interfaces as the db server will muddle your waters quite a bit given you'll have odd routing patterns for client => Web => Database.

Mind you if this is just for testing, LB should be one VM and web/database can be on a single box.

If this is for a staging or production, go separate VM.  If you have LB issues, restarting your whole DB and application doesn't make sense.

Comment: The cost should be minimal for a software LB solution against a VM (small vm footprint for HA Proxy, more cost for larger full ADC functionality like F5 BIG-IP).

Comment: Helps to know if this is for production, staging (should mirror production) or just a lab app for testing.

Answer (score 1):

It is not good idea at all. You can find reasons in previous posts, I will just add problem of scaling and failover. I think you should rethink about your architecture with SPOF in mind and set it like this:

```
Internet ----> Virtual IP ----> LB1 \_____/  APP1 \    /- DB1
                          \---> LB2 /     |- APP2  >--<
                                          \  APP3 /    \- DB2
```

LB1 and LB2 are loadbalancers in failover setup with Virtual IP (you can use Keepalived for this), so when LB1 dies, LB2 gets VIP automatically and everything works. You should have replicated DB setup too, so when one of DB server dies, app is using another one. LBs can also work as firewalls and only "Internet-facing things" at all, APP and DB servers doesn't need to have public IP at all.